# Как писать ошибки php в лог httpd?

Tags: php, apache, httpd

Здравствуйте.

Достался в наследство сервер на обслуживание на CentOS 6.

На нем httpd + php.

Сейчас ошибки php пишутся в лог /var/log/php_error.log

Конфигурация php.ini:

```
error_log = /var/log/php_error.log
log_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

В конфиге apache прописаны настройки:

```
ErrorLog logs/error_log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog logs/access_log combined
```

Как сделать так, чтобы ошибки php попадали в лог apache, а именно в /var/log/httpd/error_log ?

Answer (score 1):

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log", "/path_to_log/php-error.log");
error_log( "Test Error!" );
```

Вот и все :)

Comment: Я так понимаю, это кусок php-скрипта. Я же спрашиваю, как в принципе, на уровне сервера задать глобальные настройки.

Comment: Павел, точно так же, в настройках php.ini

Comment: В настройках php прописаны эти настройки, что я и указал в стартовом сообщении. Вопрос в том, как писать логи Php в логи апача? Просто задать  error_log тоже файл, что и у апача?

Comment: но делать это на уровне сервера на самом деле плохая практика. Если Вы хотите вникнуть в логирование с головой, рекомендую познакомится со стэком ELK

Comment: да, попробуйте, но у них разный синтаксис, любая тулза для парсинга логов вылетит с Exception'ом